# setLatitude setLongitude NullPointer exception

Tags: android, location, nullpointerexception

I have a location:

`public Location temp;`

Now I want remember some coordinates on the map, so I do this:

double a = 40.156729, b = 44.47197;

```
temp.setLatitude(40.156729);
temp.setLongitude(44.47197);
```

This throws NullPointerException.
I also tried in this way:

```
double a = 40.156729, b = 44.47197;
temp.setLatitude(a);
temp.setLongitude(b);
```

But still the same.

Logcat:

```
06-05 09:32:55.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1370): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Thanks.

Comment: where temp is initialized......code please

Comment: Does your temp object is initialized?

Comment: Make sure you are initializing it properly.

Comment: [Why getting NullPointerException ?](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/why-nullpointerexception-occures-in.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have yout initialized the Location object? For instance:

```
Location temp  = new Location(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

Answer (score 5):

Initialise the variable

```
  public Location temp = new Location("");
```